# Rust Lifetime mismatch in trait method

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, lifetime

I'm working through the Rust book, and trying to implement logic to allow text to only be added to a blog `Post` if its in the `Draft` state, as can be found [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch17-03-oo-design-patterns.html) (one of the suggested exercises).

The idea is to implement the state pattern in Rust using structs and traits.  I simply want to pass a string slice to a default implementation of `add_text` which returns an empty string slice if not in the `Draft` state.  Then I'll override the default implementation for the `Draft` state and return the string slice that was passed in for the text in the `Draft` state.

```
pub struct Post {
    state: Option<Box<dyn State>>,
    content: String,
}

impl Post {
    pub fn new() -> Post {
        Post {
            state: Some(Box::new(Draft {})),
            content: String::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_text(&mut self, text: &str) {
        let text = self.state.as_ref().unwrap().add_text(text);
        // self.state.as_ref().unwrap().add_content(text)
        self.content.push_str(text);
    }

    //snip

trait State {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>;
    fn approve(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>;
    fn content<'a>(&self, post: &'a Post) -> &'a str {
        ""
    }
    fn reject(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>;
    fn add_text(&self, text: &str) -> &str {
        ""
    }
}

struct Draft {}

impl State for Draft {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        Box::new(PendingReview {})
    }
    fn approve(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        self // don't want to approve a draft before review!
    }
    fn reject(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        self // reject doesn't do anything on a draft!
    }
    fn add_text(&self, text: &str) -> &str {
        text
    }
}
```

I'm getting a lifetime mismatch on the very last method above `add_text` inside `impl State for Draft`.  The message reads:

```
lifetime mismatch

...but data from `text` is returned hererustc(E0623)
lib.rs(67, 30): this parameter and the return type are declared with different lifetimes...
lib.rs(67, 39):
lib.rs(68, 9): ...but data from `text` is returned here
```

I'm new to Rust and can't get the lifetime annotations right in this case.  I tried explicit lifetime annotations but it didn't help.  Also, I know that since one of the references is `&self` all lifetime parameters should have the same lifetime as `&self` automatically (I think?).

Can someone enlighten me on getting this code to compile? It also may be useful to those using the book in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were tripped over by [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html):

> Each elided lifetime in input position becomes a distinct lifetime parameter.
>
> If there is exactly one input lifetime position (elided or not), that lifetime is assigned to all elided output lifetimes.
>
> If there are multiple input lifetime positions, but one of them is `&self` or `&mut self`, the lifetime of `self` is assigned to all elided output lifetimes.
>
> Otherwise, it is an error to elide an output lifetime.

In your code `fn add_text(&self, text: &str) -> &str`, the returned `&str` picks up the elided lifetime from `&self`, but then it is actually the second parameter. A mismatch as if it were:

```rust
fn add_text<'a, 'b>(&'a self, text: &'b str) -> &'a str {
    text
}
```

The trick is to make lifetime explicit here:

```rust
trait State {
    fn add_text<'a>(&'a self, text: &'a str) -> &'a str;
}

impl State for Draft {
    fn add_text<'a>(&'a self, text: &'a str) -> &'a str {
        text
    }
}
```

If you want a slightly more general version:

```rust
trait State {
    fn add_text<'a, 'b: 'a>(&'a self, text: &'b str) -> &'a str;
}

impl State for Draft {
    fn add_text<'a, 'b: 'a>(&'a self, text: &'b str) -> &'a str {
        text
    }
}
```

Here it says as long as `text` outlives `&self` all is good. You decide if the extra generic lifetime is worth the trouble.

Comment: Thank you very much; I had an inclination to try this but I was stubborn in believing my understanding of elision rules and didn't try it.  I just assumed that since the output lifetime matching the lifetime of `&self` would be inferred to be longer than the lifetime of `text` and wouldn't need to specify.  But clearly that's not the case.